# Magento 2: Get qty of added product in cart

Tags: magento2, product, cart, qty

I want to get total quantity of product added in cart by product ID.
I use `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` class to get all items in cart.

```
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->getProductId() == '101') {
        return $item->getQty(); //Get product qty
    }
}
```

This will get product qty added in cart. But if I have 30 products in cart it will loop 30 times.

**Is there any way to get qty of single product without looping all products from cart?**

Any help appreciated!

Comment: If u can get the total collection of cart items, then u can sort it by using required Product ID. From that you can get the required quantity..

Comment: @PavanKumar Can you provide code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly get the total qty of `quote` without using `foreach` by using this method

`$quote->getItemsQty();`

If you want to check in `order` object then you can get it by,

`$order->getTotalQtyOrdered()`

Where `$quote` is `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote` object and

`$order` is `Magento\Sales\Model\Order` object.

Answer (score 2):

```
//add code in list.phtml
<div>
    <?php
    $IdDoProduto = $_product->getId();
    $cart = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
    $itens = $cart->getQuote()->getItems();

    foreach ($itens as $item){
        if($IdDoProduto == $item->getProduct_id()){
            echo $item->getQty();
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried the above code in list.phtml. but quote returns empty

Answer (score 0):

You can get item qty from bellow code it will check for the product in current item collection and return qty if product is available...

```
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$productId="your_product_id";
foreach ( $items as $item) {
        if ($item->getProductId() == $productId) {
            return $item->getQty();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know how to get all products from cart. I already declare in question. I want to get product qty by product ID.

Comment: it will return you product Qty.. check the code I have added condition for check productID and if product ID match with the Item collection Product ID it will return only product Qty not full Item collection

Comment: I mean `$cart->getQuote()->getAllItems()` this function get all items from cart and we need foreach to load each item. but I don't won't foreach to load all items. For ex. I have 50 product in cart then it will loop 50 times.

Answer (score 0):

This causes issues for module developers who need to work out what item was added to the cart for a custom module.

Possible Solution

Right now we have:

```
$this->checkoutSession->getLastAddedProductId();
```

To get the last added product however there is no way to fetch the item id. A possible solution is to give us a saved session for getLastAddedItemId for example:

```
$this->checkoutSession->getLastAddedItemId();
```